# In MySQL, why do I have to define ForeignKey relationships?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

Why can't I just leave those relationships out?

What's the point of them?

I can stil run queries and treat them like it a relationship myself...

Comment: It's even worse than you imagine: foreign keys will slow down updates! But as others have urged, befire you dismiss FKs, read up on [data integrity constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can always leave the foreign key constraints out but then you will be responsible about the integrity of your data. If you use foreign key constraints, then you won't have to worry about the referential integrity among tables. You can read more about referential integrity from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity). I will also try to explain it with an example below.

Think of a shopping cart scenario. You have three tables: `item`, `shopping_cart` and `shopping_cart_item`. You can choose not to define any relationship between these tables, that's fine for any SQL solution. When user starts shopping, you create a shopping cart by adding a `shopping_cart` entry. As user adds items to his shopping cart, you save this information by adding rows to `shopping_cart_item` table.

One problem may occur at this step: If you have a buggy code that assigns incorrect `shopping_cart_id`'s to `shopping_cart_item`s, then you will definitely end up with incorrect data! Yes, you can have this case even with a foreign key constraint if the assigned id actually exists in the `shopping_cart` table. But this error will be more detectable when a foreign key exists since it would not insert `shopping_cart_item` record when the foreign key constraint fails.

Let's continue with the assumption that your code is not buggy and you won't have first type of referential integrity. Then suddenly a user wants to stop shopping and delete the cart and you chose to implement this case by deleting the `shopping_cart` and `shopping_cart_item` entries. Then you will have to delete entries in both tables with two separate queries. If something goes wrong after you delete `shopping_cart` entries, then you will again have a referential integrity problem: You will have `shopping_cart_item`s that are not related to any `shopping_cart`. You will then have to introduce transaction managing, try to provide meaningful data to your business logic about the error happened in data access layer, etc..

In this type of scenario's, foreign keys can save life. You can define a foreign key constraint that will prevent insertion of any *sort of incorrect* data and you can define cascade operations that will automatically perform deletion of related data.

If there is anything unclear, just leave a comment and I can improve the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by data integrity?

Answer (score 2):

You create FOREIGN KEYs to instruct the database engine to ensure that you never perform an action on the database that creates invalid records.

So, if you create a FOREIGN KEY relationship between `users.id` and `visits.userid` the engine will refuse to perform any actions that result in a `userid` value in `visits` that does not exist in `users`.  This might be adding an unknown `userid` to `visits`, removing an `id` from `users` that already exists in `visits`, or updating either field to "break" the relationship.

That is why PRIMARY and FOREIGN KEYs are referred to as *referential integrity* constraints.  The tell your database engine how to keep your data correct.

Comment: "PRIMARY and FOREIGN KEYs are referred to as relational integrity constraints" -- they are?! The SQL Standard spec deliberately avoid the use of the term "relation" and its derivatives. I think you mean,  "`FOREIGN KEY`s are referred to as referential integrity constraints." Note s FK can reference an `UNIQUE` constraint and I don't think PKs are referential integrity constraints.

Comment: That is correct.  For "relational" I meant to write "referential".  But primary and unique keys are certainly part of the referential integrity system.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what the others have said about why you technically want (actually: need) them: 
foreign key constraints also **document** your model.

When looking at a model without FK constraints you have no idea which table relates to which. But with FK constraints in place you immediately see how things belong together.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't allow you to enter an id which does not exist in another table, for example, if you have products and you keep owner Id, by creating a foreign key ton the owner id to id field of the owners table, you do not allow users to create an object record which has an owner id which does not exist in the owner table. such things are called [referential intergrity.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key constraint helps you ensure referential integrity.

If you delete a row in one table, mysql can automatically delete all rows in other tables that  the deleted row refers to via the foreign key. You can also make it reject the delete command.

Also when you try to insert a row, mysql can automatically create new rows in other tables, so the foreign key does not refer to nothing.

That is what referential integrity is all about.

Answer (score 0):

Databases can be affected by more than just the application. Not all data changes go through the application even if they are supposed to. People change stuff directly on the database all the time.  Rules that need to apply to all data all the time belong on the database. Suppose you can update the prices of your stock. That's great for updating anindividual price. But what happens when the boss decides to raise all prices by 15%. No one is going to go through and change 10,000 prices one at a time through the GUI, they are going to write a quick SQL script to do the update. Or suppose two suppliers join together to have one company and you want to change all of thie items to be the new company.   Those kinds of changes happen to databases every day and they too need to follow the rules for data integrity.

New developers may not know about all the places where the foreign key relationships should exist and thus make mistakes which cause the data to be no longer useful.

Databases without foreign key constraints have close to a  100% chance of having bad data in them. Do you really want to have orders where you can't identify who the customers were?

THe FKS will prevent you from deleting a customer who has orders for instance or if you use a natural key of company_name and the name changes, all related records must be changed with the key change.

Or suppose you decide to put a new GUI together and dump the old one, then you might have to figure out all the FK relationships again (because you are using a different datalayer or ORM) and the chances are you might miss some.

It is irresponsible in the extreme to not put in FK relationships. You are risking the lifeblood of your company's business because you think it is a pain to do. I'd fire you if you suggested not using FKs because I would know I couldn't trust my company's data to you.

Comment: "Databases without foreign key constraints have close to a 100% chance of having bad data in them" -- I couldn't agree more. Then again, databases without `CHECK` constraints have close to a 100% chance of having bad data in them, so that would apply to 100% of databases on mySQL ;)